# Replacing table name and column name before and after query execution in Yii1.x

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I want to replace table name and field name with some other name before and after execution of queries (CRUD operation).

Let's say I have a DB table - TBL1 with fields (col1, col2, col3) that is basically a users table with fields (id, name, email) but with obfuscated names.

I have SQL queries(select,insert,update) written in Yii controller/model using real names (users, id, name, email) but just before execution these names should get replaced by obfuscated names which are actually present in DB (TBL1, col1, col2, col3).

Similarly, after execution obfuscated names (TBL1, col1, col2, col3) should get replaced by real names (users, id, name, email) for further processing in controller code.

Comment: Huh? Love to know why you think this is a good/necessary thing to do please.

Comment: Actually we need to deploy whole project (code & db) into client's server so we want to obfuscate code & db before migration. We can obfuscate code using Zend Guard but to obfuscate DB (in order to do not expose db structure to the client or making it difficult to understand structure) we need to do this.

Comment: Obfuscating DB schema sounds like ridiculous idea. Even you will be able to do this (which will be really hard in case of complex queries) it gives you pretty close to nothing, since usually it is pretty easy to guess column/table name based on its content. And fixing bugs based on obfuscated query will be a nightmare.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I mentioned, we want to make it difficult for others to understand the DB structure by obfuscating it the way I have mentioned above. Would be a great help if someone can give some idea that how can we achieve this in Yii1.x

Answer (score 0):

Just run basic command like

```php
<?php
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->execute('ALTER TABLE ...');
// your queries here
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->execute('ALTER TABLE ...');
```

This is the easiest way I think